# What space is required to build a Singularity container?

Tags: singularity-container

I've got a `def` file to build a container (within a Vagrant VM). If I build as a sandbox:

```
sudo singularity build --sandbox mytest/ mytest.def
```

then the build completes. However, if I build straight to a container:

```
sudo singularity build mytest.sif mytest.def
```

then I get an error:

```
FATAL:   While performing build: While creating SIF: while creating container: writing data object for SIF file: copying data object file to SIF file: write mytest.sif: no space left on device
```

If I try and convert the sandbox to a container:

```
sudo singularity build mytest.sif mytest/
```

then I get the same error.

The docs don't give an indication of the amount of space needed for a build vs sandbox. I could increase the size of the Vagrant VM, but it would be good to have an idea how much I should increase it by to ensure that the build is successful

Answer (score 3):

The size is dependent on the image. If you're building from a docker image, you can look at that to get a general idea based on its size. It's important to know where to put the extra drive space, however.

Singularity uses a tmp dir (default: `/tmp`) and a cache dir (default: `$HOME/.singularity/cache`) in addition to the directory you're building in. Note that cache dir uses `/root/.singularity/cache` not your user home on `sudo singularity build` because of `sudo`. VMs often have small `/`, `/root`, and/or `/tmp` partitions by default. This has been a gotcha for me in the past and may also be affecting you.

You can use the `--tmpdir` flag on build to change that to somewhere that has more space if desired ([see documentation here](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.4/user-guide/cli/singularity_build.html)).

To change the default cache dir you have to set the environment variable `SINGULARITY_CACHEDIR`, with details on specifics [in the documentation here](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.4/user-guide/build_env.html#cache-folders). You can also set the `SINGULARITY_TMPDIR` in the same manner instead of using the `--tmpdir` flag. It is sometimes nice to keep all the environment modifications in one place.